# Twig loop and skip in loop

Tags: symfony, twig

I pretty new to Twig first of all!

I'm trying to loop through an array of products, like so:

```
{% for product in products %}
```

What I further try to do is to check if one of the `product.title` equals the name `lookbook`.
if so then this product cannot be showed in my template/page. The things I tried just display an empty `div` instead of not showing anything.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

What I have so far:

```
   {% for product in products %}
   {% if product.title == 'lookbook' %}
      .... dont show?? ....
   {% else %}
   <div class="product>
     <h3>{{ product.fulltitle }}</h3>  
     <a href="{{ product.url | url }}" title="{{ product.fulltitle }}">
       <img src="{{ product.image | url_image('220x220x2', product.fulltitle) }}" />
     </a>
   </div>

   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

I also tried:

```
{% for product in products and product.title != 'lookbook' %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it has a title set?

Answer (score 3):

[Official doc :](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html)

```
{% for user in users if user.active %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
```

In your case :

```
{% for product in products if product.title != 'lookbook' %}
```

### Update 08/2021

> Tip
>
> As of Twig 2.10, use the filter filter instead, or an if condition
> inside the for body (if your condition depends on a variable updated
> inside the loop and you are not using the loop variable).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% if product.title != 'lookbook' %}
        <div class="product>
             <h3>{{ product.fulltitle }}</h3>  
             <a href="{{ product.url | url }}" title="{{ product.fulltitle }}">
               <img src="{{ product.image | url_image('220x220x2', product.fulltitle) }}" />
             </a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: _You can't combine your for and if in the same statement_ Wrong you dont know how but it's possible, read my answer

Comment: I stand corrected. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition